# Remove timestamp property older than one year from current Time in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, ecmascript-6, datetime-format

I have an object with a timestamp in milliseconds:

```
const indexes = {
      index1: 1490659200000 // 2017-03-28
      index2: 1490659200000 // 2017-03-28
      index3: 1498608000000 // 2017-06-28
}
```

How to delete an index where timestamp older than one year from the current time. `new Date().getTime()` -`1522269838207`.
Actually, what is the faster way loop through object and delete timestamp older than 1 year. Maybe better just convert to yyyy-mm-dd and than comparing by yyyy, mm-dd

```
Object.keys(indexes).forEach(i => {
   if (indexes[i] < new Date().getTime())
     delete indexes[i];
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const YEAR_IN_MS = 31556952000; // Year in milliseconds
var now = Data.now(); // current timestamp
Object.keys(indexes).forEach(i => {
    if (now - indexes[i] >= YEARS_IN_MS) // get difference time and check if greater or equal than year
        delete indexes[i];
})
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` along with the operation `one year - date in object`

This approach will create a new array with the dates not older than one year.

```js
const indexes = { index1: 1490659200000, index2: 1490659200000,  index3: 1498608000000}

var oneYearAgo = new Date();
oneYearAgo.setFullYear( oneYearAgo.getFullYear() - 1 );

var result = Object.keys(indexes).reduce((a, c) => {
  if (oneYearAgo.getTime() - indexes[c] > 0) a.push(indexes[c]);
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how exact the "older than one year" has to be. If we consider that year has 365 days then:

```
const indexes = {
    index1: 1490659200000, // 2017-03-28
    index2: 1490659200000, // 2017-03-28
    index3: 1498608000000 // 2017-06-28
}

var currentDate = new Date();
var year = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

for (var index in indexes) {
    if (indexes[index] < (currentDate - year)) delete indexes[index];
}
```